# Incorrect Syntax near 'WHERE'

Tags: sql

I am updating my DB through Datagridview. Here is my Update_Button code:

```
 public void SaveDataSet(DataTable table)
{

  foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
  {

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(
      @"update dbo.JobStatus 
        SET ShipTransmitStatus = @TransmitStatus, 
          ShipTrackingNumber = @TrackingNum, 
          Carrier = @Carrier, 
          ShipmentProcessedBy = @ProcessedBy, 
          ShipMethodTransmitted = @MethodTransmitted,
        WHERE JobTableId = @JobID ", _mySqlConnec);

    //Updated the parameters to the SQL Query!
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TransmitStatus", row["Status"].ToString()));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TrackingNum", row["Tracking#"].ToString()));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Carrier", row["Carrier"]));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProcessedBy", row["ProcessedBy"].ToString()));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MethodTransmitted", row["MethodTransmitted"].ToString()));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@JobID", row["JobID"].ToString()));

    cmd2.Connection = _mySqlConnec;
    _mySqlConnec.Open();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    _mySqlConnec.Close();
  }


}
```

And this is my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.JobNumber as Job#,dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.PatientName,
       dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.CustomerAccountName as Name, COALESCE(InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressAddr2 + ' ','') + COALESCE(InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressAddr3+' ','') as Address,
       dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressCity as City, dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressState as State,
       dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressPostalCode as ZipCode, dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressCountry as Country , dbo.JobStatus.ShipTransmitStatus as Status, dbo.JobStatus.ShipTrackingNumber as Tracking#, dbo.JobStatus.Carrier, dbo.JobStatus.ShipMethodTransmitted as MethodTransmitted,
       dbo.JobStatus.DateShipTransmitProcessed as DateProcessed, dbo.JobStatus.ShipmentProcessedBy as ProcessedBy, dbo.JobStatus.Critical,  dbo.JobStatus.JobTableId as JobID, dbo.JobStatus.InvoiceStatus,
       dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.Quantity, dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.ChargeGroup
       FROM dbo.InvoiceLineDetail INNER JOIN
       dbo.View_JobsToShipCount ON dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.CustomerAccountName = dbo.View_JobsToShipCount.CompanyName INNER JOIN
       dbo.JobStatus ON dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.JobID = dbo.JobStatus.JobTableId
       WHERE (dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.ChargeGroup = N'Lens')
```

I am getting an error: Incorrect Syntax near 'WHERE'. Could find out the problem :(

Answer (score 8):

Remove last comma from:

```
ShipMethodTransmitted = @MethodTransmitted,
```

i.e. change it to:

```
ShipMethodTransmitted = @MethodTransmitted
```

As a general answer for these kinds of errors:

1. Look around near the keyword suggested in error message.
2. If your error message gave you a line at which the error is look at that. line

That's exactly what I did now. I looked near WHERE and saw the extra comma.

Answer (score 3):

```
ShipMethodTransmitted = @MethodTransmitted,
```

remove the comma after @Method...

?

Answer (score 3):

In the SaveDataSet function, the SQL command has one extra comma before the WHERE clause.