# Finding the cause of Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following error from SQL Server:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       cpt.Cpt_id AS ID_Entreprise,
       enta.entApp,
       enta.entJuri,
       cli.RaisocA,
       cli.RaisocB,
       cli.AdresA,
       cli.AdresB,
       cli.Cpostal,
       cli.Burdist,
       ins.Site_id,
       ins.Inscrip_id,
       '' AS CdGraReg,
       '' AS CaisseSS,
       '' AS CentreSS,
       cpt.Login,
       cli.RaisocB AS Raisoc,
       ct.Entappcr,
       ct.Cont,
       ct.Souscont,
       ct.Sptf,
       ctcb.Socuti,
       (CASE
             WHEN ct.typepdt = 'R' THEN (CASE WHEN (ctcb.entjuriais IS NULL OR ctcb.entjuriais = '') THEN 'E' ELSE 'R' END)
             ELSE ct.typepdt
        END) AS typepdt,
       ct.Scont,
       ct.Siret,
       ctcb.Datefcb,
       ctcb.Dtfineffcb,
       ctcb.Stacb,
       ctcb.Libstacb,
       ctcb.Perap,
       ctcb.Libperap,
       ctcb.Deremis,
       ctcb.Derregl,
       ISNULL(EntTPG.EntiteTPG, '') AS EntiteTPG,
       CASE ct.Typepdt
            WHEN 'R' THEN CASE ISNULL(RegRet.Reg, 0)WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            WHEN 'I' THEN CASE ISNULL(RegIFC.Reg, 0)WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            ELSE 0
       END AS UC,
       CASE ct.Typepdt
            WHEN 'R' THEN CASE ISNULL(RegRet.Reg, 0)WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE RegRet.isArt39 END
            ELSE 0
       END AS Art39,
       ctcb.Cb,
       ctcb.Cnt_bo_ve_actif,
       ct.Sta,
       ct.Libsta,
       ct.Dateff,
       ctcb.Date_hors_infocentre AS Date_hors_infocentre_CtCb,
       CASE WHEN RegMens.reg IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS mensualisation,
       CASE WHEN RegRep.reg IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS repartition,
       CASE WHEN RegOptFin.reg IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS optFin,
       ctcb.Socuti,
       ctcb.Libcb,
       (CASE ct.typepdt
             WHEN 'S' THEN '1'
             WHEN 'P' THEN '2'
             WHEN 'R' THEN '3'
             WHEN 'I' THEN '4'
             ELSE '5'
        END) AS orderParam,
       ct.Reg,
       ctcb.Cnt_bo_affil_sal,
       ctcb.Cnt_bo_affil_sal AS affilSalEnabled,
       ct.Siret,
       ISNULL(ctcb.AtOperationnel, 'N') AS AtOperationnel,
       ctcb.Formule,
       ctcb.FormuleSocle,
       ctcb.Srs,
       ctcb.Libstacb_vision_C,
       ct.DATENVOI,
       ct.DATREGUL,
       ct.DATPA,
       ctcb.Cnt_bo_vs_actif,
       ctcb.Vision AS Vision_Ctcb,
       ct.Vision AS Vision_Ct,
       ctcb.Valide AS Valide_Ctcb,
       ctcb.Valide_C,
       ct.ent_opt_set,
       ctcb.Cntcb_actif,
       ct.Cnt_actif,
       ctcb.Cntcb_actif,
       ct.CodeICX,
       ct.AppLeader
FROM  dbo.Inscription_site ins INNER JOIN
      dbo.Clients cli ON cli.Siret = ins.Siret INNER JOIN
      dbo.Comptes_cli cpt ON cpt.Inscrip_id = ins.Inscrip_id INNER JOIN
      dbo.ENTAPP enta ON enta.entApp = ins.Entappcr INNER JOIN
      dbo.Contratscb ctcb INNER JOIN
      dbo.Contrats ct ON ctcb.Scont = ct.Scont AND ctcb.Siret = ct.Siret LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.Asso_SocUti_ENTTPG EntTPG ON EntTPG.Socuti = ctcb.Socuti LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.Regime_IdentificationContratsRetraiteUC RegRet ON RegRet.Reg = ct.Reg LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.Regime_IdentificationContratsIFCUC RegIFC ON RegIFC.Reg = ct.Reg LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.Regime_Mensualisation RegMens ON RegMens.Reg = ct.Reg LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.Regime_Repartition RegRep ON RegRep.Reg = ct.Reg LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.Regime_OptionFinanciere RegOptFin ON RegOptFin.Reg = ct.Reg LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.Regime_ERE RegERE ON RegERE.Reg = ct.Reg
WHERE (ctcb.Stacb NOT IN ('30', '31', '35', '39')) AND (ct.Sta <> '30')
```

underline "where" but i don't know why

Comment: My guess is that you have a back character before the `WHERE`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English Speaking community, please include your errors, and question as English. You've tagged SQL Server and MySQl here, however, this clearly appears to be SQL Server as well. Finally, whitespace and line breaks are wonderful things; I suggest using it when writing code to make it far more readable.

Comment: Is it bad that Ive seen so many errors from Sql Server, that I even recognise them in a language I don't speak :|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect Syntax near 'WHERE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455363/incorrect-syntax-near-where)

Comment: Missing ON clause. Like 4th or 5th JOIN. `INNER JOIN
      dbo.Contratscb ctcb INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Where is `dbo.Contratscb ctcb`'s `ON` clause?

Comment: Missing join on `INNER JOIN dbo.Contratscb AS ctcb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsers tend to give you error messages, but they are less than perfect. Sometimes they are unable to show you exactly where your syntax error is, and instead report the end of the block where an error in parsing exists.

In your case, when the parser gets to the `WHERE` part it realises the block preceding it has an error and reports that location.

The error is you forgot to qualify the `INNER JOIN` to `dbo.Contratscb ctcb` with an `ON` clause

```
....
dbo.Comptes_cli cpt ON cpt.Inscrip_id = ins.Inscrip_id INNER JOIN
dbo.ENTAPP enta ON enta.entApp = ins.Entappcr INNER JOIN
dbo.Contratscb ctcb INNER JOIN <-- should be an ON here
dbo.Contrats ct ON ctcb.Scont = ct.Scont AND ctcb.Siret = ct.Siret LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Asso_SocUti_ENTTPG EntTPG ON EntTPG.Socuti = ctcb.Socuti LEFT OUTER JOIN
....
```

Answer (score 2):

The on clause is missing:

```
INNER JOIN
      dbo.Contratscb ctcb INNER JOIN
```

Comment: Well spotted. This may be one of the biggest arguments for keeping a join on a single line instead of being split across multiple lines. I know the syntax the OP posted is very popular but I find it user hostile and painful to work with.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes you are right, the syntax is quite misleading... putting it onto a single row might prevent future mistakes

Comment: I should say formatting, not syntax. The syntax doesn't change. :)